holomorphic on the ball of every $\mathbb C^2$ $\implies$ holomorphic on the entire ball of $\mathbb C^m$
Denote by $D_{a, b}^{m}$ the spherical shell
$$D_{a, b}^{m}=\{z\in\mathbb C^m~|~a<|z|^2<b\}.$$
A complex manifold $M^{n}$ is said to obey the Hartogs phenomenon, if for any $1>a \geq 0$, any holomorphic map from $D_{a, 1}^{2}$ into $M$ can be extended to a holomorphic map from the unit ball $B^{2}$ into $M$.
Then the book says,

If $M$ obeys Hartogs phenomenon, then clearly for any $m \geq 2$ and any $0 \leq a<b$, any holomorphic map from $D_{a, b}^{m}$ into $M$ can be extended to a holomorphic map from the ball $B_{b}^{m}$ into $M$. One may restrict such a map to the intersection of $2$-dimensional (real $4$-dimensional) complex plane with the spherical shell and then apply the definition.

This map is indeed holomorphic on the ball of every $\mathbb C^2$. But how do we get the map to be holomorphic on the entire ball of $\mathbb C^m$ when we piece these $\mathbb C^2$ together to form the entire $\mathbb C^m$? Any help would appreciated!

This is another theorem due to Hartogs, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs%27s_theorem_on_separate_holomorphicity

Saying $2$-dimensional complex plane is beyond confusing. You mean various $1$-dimensional complex lines. Indeed, Hartogs proves that you only need lines parallel to the $m$ coordinate axes.

@TedShifrin No, the definition of Hartogs phenomenon is $D_{a, 1}^{2}$, and $D_{a, b}^{m}:={z\in\mathbb C^m~|~a<|z|^2<b}$. I have edited my post to avoid confusion.

Moishe Kohan's comment is very helpful but the situation is somewhat different. So I want to explain the details clearly.
Hartogs' another theorem says, every separate holomorphic (holomorphic on each variable) function is holomorphic. So it suffices to prove for any $m-1$ complex constants $c_1,\cdots,c_{i-1},c_{i+1},\cdots,c_m$, the function is holomorphic on
$$B^m\cap\{(c_1,\cdots,c_{i-1},z_i,c_{i+1},\cdots,c_m)\in\mathbb C^m~|~z_i\in\mathbb C\}=:B^m\cap l.$$
Consider the $2$-dimensional (real $4$-dimensional) complex plane $\Sigma$ determined by the bi-parametric equation
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l} z_1=c_1s,  \\ \cdots\cdots \\ z_{i-1}=c_{i-1}s, \\ z_i=t, \\ z_{i+1}=c_{i+1}s, \\ \cdots\cdots \\ z_m=c_ms. \end{array} \right.$$
We have $l\subset\Sigma$ and the function is holomorphic on $B^m\cap\Sigma$ by definition, thus it is holomorphic on $B^m\cap l$.
